# Can't hide my custom tabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, tabbar

I'm using this example: https://github.com/tciuro/CustomTabBar for a tabbar. I'm trying to hide it with a button push up but the center picture will always stay visible. Tried a lot of methods like `self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar.hidden=YES;` but the center picture will stay shown even if It's added as a sub view.

Update:There's a solution for hiding the tabbar but not the rectangle background. I'm trying to make it hidden with no animation.

Comment: File an issue on the repo.

Comment: Other people already filed an issue on that matter month ago but the developer ignored that so i thought maybe someone here will come to the rescue.

Comment: You didn't take any further action, and neither did the person who posted the original problem.  How do you expect bugs to get fixed without providing a use-case to reproduce the problem?  Go to the repo and post a comment that shows what you're doing, what you expect it to do, and why you think it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed In my fork. you gotta call `((WBTabBarController*)self.tabbarcontroller).tabbarHidden = YES`

https://github.com/Daij-Djan/CustomTabBar/tree/master/CustomTabBar

Pull Request to original repo:

https://github.com/tciuro/CustomTabBar/pull/2 && https://github.com/tciuro/CustomTabBar/pull/3

Comment: Please post a PR to the repo that references the issue so this doesn't happen to anyone else.  :)

Comment: sure,  that was the point... :)

Comment: I downloaded the fixed code and added `- (IBAction)xxx:(UIButton *)sender {self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;}` to one of the views. When i click the button the tabbar is gone but the center picture is still there.

Comment: as said, it's `((WBTabBarController*)controller).tabBarHidden = YES`

Comment: the original author didnt place the button ON the tabbar so I decided to keep that and make a new property

Comment: It should be `((WBTabBarController*)self.tabBarController).tabBarHidden = YES;`

Comment: Now everything is hidden but there's a black bar instead. Any way to make it disappear completely and show the background picture like a normal tabbar that is hidden?

Comment: I see you wrote a comment about it in the repo but I don't see a change in the code. You uploaded the fix yet?

Comment: my repo updated & https://github.com/tciuro/CustomTabBar/pull/3, sorry had to leave for xmas festivities this morning and only now managed to update github